# Track number of pageviews and duration after user hits specific URL

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to track the number of pageviews and the session duration after a user goes to a search page. Is there a way to do this in GA or would have to setup an event in tag manager? This would not always be the landing page.

Comment: Have you tried using flow visualization?    http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/10/19/path-analysis-in-google-analytics-with-flow-visualization/